# java create and start stored procedure in Mongo?

Tags: java, mongodb, stored-procedures

In order to minimize maintance cost, I'd like to know whether it is possible to create and start a stored procedure in Mongo by Java.

in this stored procedure, I want aggregate one collection via mapReduce and store the result into another collection.

Any comment and help appreciated!
Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 3):

You can create stored procedures on MongoDB in form of Javascript functions which are stored in the special collection db.system.js, but that's usually not advisable. Most of the reasons why stored procedures are useful for relational databases do not apply to MongoDB. Instead of calling a server-sided function from Java you should just implement said function directly in Java.

But when you still want to use them, creating such functions is documented as "[storing functions server-sided](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Server-side+Code+Execution#Server-sideCodeExecution-Storingfunctionsserverside)". To execute them, you can use [DB.command()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#command%28com.mongodb.DBObject%29) or [DB.doEval()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DB.html#doEval%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).